# Facebook SDK 4.0 App Invites for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook SDK version 4.0. I am trying to make a demo for App Invite. I am following all the steps mentioned on the Facebook Developer Docs.

I can see my passed app link and image on when FB Invite Dialog opens, Even I can able to see my friends and select among them. After that I am getting issue. Dialog shows error but no description. Please see attached screenshot.

If anyone have implemented it then help me out.

[image]

I used below code,

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My App Link"]];
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<preview image>"];

    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                 delegate:self];
```

Comment: "After that I am getting issue" - What issue? What is your code?

Comment: I am also having the same problem.  How did you solve it? Can you share your answer with us.

Comment: I have created my app link from here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1397520690559248/?platform=app-links-host. then you can sue that app link created for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue.

In my case,I was using my website URL as my App Link URL and My website was having wrong fbAppId in its meta data, which caused this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your Facebook app is live, that means there will be some information you have to fill out, as per a bug I reported, they said for tests they don't need to be yours, just valid info, like valid App Store ID in your Developer iOS Settings and privacy policy URLs.